# Preloader does not preload and loads the page a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this nice jQuery [preloader/progress bar](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/), but I cannot get it to work as it is supposed to. The problem is that it first loads my page and after my whole page is loaded the 0%-100% bar displays quickly, after that it reloads my page again. So it does not show the progress bar BEFORE the page loads and it loads the page a second time as well.

Here is my implementation code:

```
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.queryloader2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("body").queryLoader2();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    My content...No other reference in here for the Jquery preloader
</body>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be *very, very wrong* here, but in my opinion:

1. The plugin is flawed.
2. You have some issue in your page that causes a redirect.

I have created **[a test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFvqW/2/)** and found out the following:

1. **If there are no images** on the page, then the plugin's private function `completeImageLoading();` **is never called** because it is only bound to the image elements. When there are no images -> there's no binding -> no triggering -> nothing completes -> you stay with overlay 0% as demonstrated by the fiddle *that is NOT RUN* (jsfiddle doesn't see relative images when the page is not run).
2. The plugin doesn't take into consideration remote images. So if you declare them like so `<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">` - then it won't work because the plugin doesn't recognize them. In fact it is using `$.ajax` to load images which, obviously, generates a error when trying to access another domain.
3. The plugin doesn't reload the page (at least in Google Chrome)... check your console output while in the fiddle. It displays the message once per click on Run.

**Suggestions:**

1. Make sure you **provide at least one *relative* or *background* image** (though I haven't tested backgrounds...) for the plugin to work.
2. Show us more code. The fiddle demonstrates that **the plugin does NOT cause page reload** (at least in Chrome... are you using another browser?). It must be something you made that interferes here.
3. **Specify some options** for the plugin (behaves weird when there are none).

---

**Edit regarding preloader**

Regarding preloader... if displaying progress is not mandatory for you, then you can just use a `window.onload` trick. On DOM ready `$(...)` you create an opaque page overlay with a "Please wait..." message and some animation if you fancy it. Then you wait for **[window.onload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)** which *"fires at the end of the document loading process... when all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading."* When `window.onload` triggers, you just remove your overlay and voila - the page is ready!

**Edit 2 regarding preloader**

Actually, you don't even need `$(...)`... what the hell was I thinking? Just create your overlay (a simple div with a unique id) in your html, style it so that it fills the screen and give it a `z-index:1337` CSS attribute so that it covers the entire page. Then, on window.onload:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Grab a reference to your overlay element:
    var overlay = document.getElementById('myOverlay');
    // Check if the overlay really exists
    // and if it is really appended to the DOM,
    // because if not - removeChild throws an error
    if (overlay && overlay.parentNode && overlay.parentNode.nodeType === 1) {
        // Remove overlay from DOM:
        overlay.parentNode.removeChild(overlay);
        // Now trash it to free some resources:
        overlay = null;
    }
};
```

Of course, it's not really a preloader, but simply an imitation.

Here's **[a working fiddle you can play with](http://jsfiddle.net/DZy75/1/)**.

P.S. I personally don't appreciate preloaders, but that's just me...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I have a lot of code...And I do have images. I refer to all them relatively...As I said, I used it as simple as shown, with just the body element as a reference...Ok, will try to specify some options and let you know. But my main aim is not for preloading images, but the whole web page...Am I using the wrong plugin here? They said it is for web pages as well...

Comment: *"What QueryLoader2 does is simply scanning the given elements for images (and background images) and preloading them before the website is visible."* < they say it and their code does just that. Apparently, the first version of QueryLoader was used to preload whole pages, but it has become obsolete and been replaced by QueryLoader2, which preloads only images. I think you're using a wrong (and buggy) plugin.

Comment: Basically, the idea to wait for images to load is not a bad one, because *usually* they take the longest time to load and thus when they are finished, the rest of the page is ready. But, well... that's not bulletproof.

Comment: @DextrousDave I have added some info about a preloader to my answer if that's of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. So if I understand correctly, the " DOM ready $(...)" function triggers before anything is loaded into the DOM and the "window.onload event"? I would really like to have something to show the user when all of the objects are busy loading, so that they won't think the page has timed ou or anything. Could you please give me more rope on how to use the DOM ready function to display a preloading message or animation? Would really appreciate. I really tried a lot of these loaders, and most of them are for images or they're just buggy/full of crap

Comment: @DextrousDave I've added a basic example demonstrating my idea. It doesn't have any animation or styling, but hopefully explains the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this(Remove the document.ready event and simply call this):-

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
            $("body").queryLoader2();
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. First of all, "body" must be defined for it to work, and second: the plugin is searching for image tags in the DOM... which is not loaded yet.