# Issue - page displayed 1sec before queryloader2 loads the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using queryloader on my website ([link](http://goo.gl/9Xt2b)). For some reason the main page appears during one second before queryloader does its job (progress bar to load images before showing the website).

I assume that this is due to the fact that the page is loaded before the queryloader script is loaded but don’t know how to fix this. For the moment the code is in the 
`$(document).ready` as suggested on the [queryloader2 website](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader2-preload-your-images-with-ease/)  and I’m calling the script (located in js/scripts.js) in my head tags.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").queryLoader2();

    $('.activity-title a').click(function() {
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

        $('.textzone:visible').fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $('#' + region).fadeIn(2000);
        });

        return false;            
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to be working for me. I can see progress bar reach 100% and as soon as it does, the overlay fades out (tested in Chrome 18 on Ubuntu). BTW - great background pictures :)

Comment: Ok thanks for your feedback - seems that the issue's only appearing with ie8 then?

Comment: This Plugin is flawed


Check this alternative

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977238/preloader-does-not-preload-and-loads-the-page-a-second-time

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring up an old thread, but just for anyone facing this problem, here's my fix..
 i added an overlay div right after the Body tag opening

```
<div id="preloader"></div>
```

And added this CSS

```
    #preloader {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;

    background-color:#fff; /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index:99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
```

and added the `onLoadComplete: hidePreLoader` to the QueryLoader options

Then on that function just hide the overlay once done.

```
function hidePreLoader() {
        $("#preloader").hide();
    }
```

That would be pretty much it, hope it helps someone out there :)

Comment: FYI looks like on the example page he uses the same thing (element with id #qLoverlay), so it's strange that it's not included in the instructions: http://scripts.gayadesign.com/queryLoader2/css/style.css